# This expression is not callable error when loading image-size through import

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use image-size npm package for my typescript project.

The problem is that if I try to load the `sizeOf` through the import syntax (`import sizeOf from 'image-size';`), then the following code fails with an error.

```
src/image.ts:52:31 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/image-size/dist/index")' has no call signatures.

52       const dimension = await sizeOf(imageFileName);
```

On the other hand, if I load with `require` like this (`const sizeOf = require('image-size');`), it works without a problem.

What can go wrong with the import syntax?

Comment: Looks like the types are missing for `image-size`. Can you try installing `npm i --save-dev @types/image-size`?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the typings of `image-size`: the [generated typings](https://unpkg.com/image-size@0.9.1/dist/index.d.ts) don't specify that the export is a function. According to the [source code](https://github.com/image-size/image-size/blob/master/lib/index.ts#L77), the function is only exported as `module.exports = ` for backwards compatibility. You could use `import {imageSize as sizeOf} from 'image-size'` instead.